# Designing under cabinet lighting with Home Automation in mind

Tags: lighting, home-automation

I am looking to install under cabinet lighting in my kitchen keeping in mind that I'd like to add a Lutron Caseta in the near future. There are 3 problems I am trying to tackle.

First, I am having a hard time selecting a Dimmable LED lighting system that will work with HomeKit, Google & Alexa and is extensible to the dimensions I have in my kitchen.

Second, I'd like to run the LED strips all through my kitchen. The total length of the LED strips I require is roughly 25 ft divided into 4 sections - 13ft, 5ft, 5ft, 1.5ft. I'd like to power them by a single outlet so I need to connect these individual sections by unlit extension cables that I can run through my cabinets. These extensions are roughly 1.5ft, 7ft, 11ft. None of the strips that I saw had extension packs had cables of the lengths I am looking for. Different brands have different connectors and don't seem to have a standard connector. I am totally open making my own extension cables if I know the connector and all I need to do is buy the cable and solder the connector on it. I'd likely just plugin the LED strip into one of the power outlets in the kitchen. Would this be a bad idea?

Finally, I am planning on adding Lutron Caseta. It would be nice if this strip would work with the Caseta bridge but this is not a hard requirement. Any suggestions on how I proceed with this project?

Thanks!

Comment: The key to dimming LEDs (especially in a striplight form factor) is the power supply/driver you are using...what are you using for that, and does it support some type of dimming on its own, or were you planning to phase-control it for dimming?

Comment: I looked at various products and they had a dimmer built in. For example, https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B075KBQ7RQ/ or https://www.amazon.com/VOCOlinc-Multicolor-Adjustable-Assistant-SmartGlow/dp/B07QNNW1Y6 My biggest unknown is connecting these individual sections together with unlit extensions cables.